# javascript - How to properly initialize timezone-js

Tags: javascript, timezone

Im trying to learn the timezone-js I got from [here](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js).
I think I followed the instructions on how to get started. I downloaded all the necessary files including the Olson files but Im getting this error when I check my firefox console: `Error: Error: Error retrieving "../files/tz/northamerica" zoneinfo files`.

My code is (**`jtimezone.html`**):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/timezone-js/src/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    timezoneJS.timezone.zoneFileBasePath = "../files/tz";
    timezoneJS.timezone.defaultZoneFile = "asia";
    timezoneJS.timezone.init();

    var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('10/31/2008', 'America/New_York');
    alert(dt);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I have set the file path for the zoneFileBasePath. Anyway my html is located at  `/home/idiotboy/Documents/timzone_test/html`. The downloaded timezone-js is at `/home/idiotboy/Documents/timzone_test/javascript`. The `tz` files are at `/home/idiotboy/Documents/timzone_test/files`.

Please help. If you can suggest a better/easier way to handle timezones in javascipt please do. Im still a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way you can test by serving these files through a web server instead of local file system?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't allow AJAX to access local filesystem. You'll need to serve you page through Apache or Nginx and open your html with the URL localhost or 127.0.0.1